# Check if an array field is set in a switch statement

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement set up which checks the value in an array field. I also want to perform slightly different logic if the array has no field with that name.

I can write the code like this, which works, but looks a little messy in my mind:

```
if (!isset($_GET['action']))
{
    require('menu.html');
}
else
{
    switch ($_GET['action'])
    {
        case 'debug':
            require('core/actions/debug.php');
            break;
        case 'submit':
            require('core/actions/submit.php');
            break;
        case 'admin':
            header("Location: /login");
            break;
    }
}
```

But would it be possible for me to instead move the logic from the `if` statement and combine it with with my `switch` logic?

In JavaScript, I could do `case undefined: ...` as just one of the cases. Can I do something similar in PHP?

Comment: Interesting question, but if it were me I would just leave as is since it should work fine with the if/else statement.  Might not be as pretty but it's not overly complex either.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_GET['action']` is empty, or does have value, but its not any of the ones you want, you can do this.

```
switch ($_GET['action'])
{
    .............
    case "":
       echo "empty or not setted";
       break;
}
```

But if `$_GET['action']` is not setted it will throw notices on every comparison (but it will enter in `case ''` anyway).

To not show the notices you could do:

```
switch (@$_GET['action'])
```

But please, don't do that!

You could do the super-switch-crazy way too:

```
switch(true){
    case !empty($_GET['action']):
            switch ($_GET['action'])
            {
                 .............
            }
        break;
   default:
      echo "not setted or empty";
      break;
}
```

Edit:

As @IQAndreas pointed out in the comments a interest solution could be:

```
switch (true)
{
    case (!isset($_GET['action']):
        require('menu.html');
        break;
    case ($_GET['action'] == 'debug'):
        require('core/actions/debug.php');
        break;
    case ($_GET['action'] == 'submit'):
        require('core/actions/submit.php');
        break;
    case ($_GET['action'] == 'admin'):
        header("Location: /login");
        break;
}
```

But the best way IMO to handle this situation is doing what you are already doing (checking if the var is `empty` or `setted`, before the `switch..case`)

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
    switch ($_GET['action'])
    {
        .............
        case "":
           echo "empty";
           break;
    }
} else {
    echo "not setted";
}
```

Comment: Ah, right, I meant to use `isset()`, not `empty()` in my example.

Comment: You could actually make that "super switch crazy way" a little nicer: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/0a8c4994d68649ba231f

Comment: @IQAndreas great way, added to the answer. Credit its all for you!